# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"name"}

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AbJj.png)Source

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" style="box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;position:absolute;left:130px;top:50px;width:220px;">
```

This is my code

```
WebElement VARName = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
    VARName.sendKeys("Krishna-05");
```

The page in this subject is a pop up page.

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"id","selector":"name"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=61.0.3163.100)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550
>   (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

I tried finding with css,xpath,name etc and no use. All of them exhibit the same error. I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Java on Eclipse.

```
package open_chrome;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Chrome_Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://<website.com>/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("docker@de.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Test1234");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > 
    form > div:nth-child(5) > button")).click();
    //Adding New VAR

    driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen224")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen367")).click();
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
//      Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String childWindow:driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
        driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("Krishna-05");
    }
```

Comment: There could be many reasons why this is happening... what have you tried to solve it other than trying different locators? Waits? Is there an IFRAME?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any locator, seems issue with wait I guess, try explicit and Implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement VARName = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
VARName.sendKeys("Krishna-05");
```

Or with Explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
WebElement VARName= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("name")));
VARName.sendKeys("Krishna-05")
```

Second thing check whether element is in frame or not, if it is in `frame`  first switch in frame and then use above code

Comment: `visibilityOfElementLocated` does not check if element is in `iframe`. It only invokes `isDisplayed()` method on the element.

Besides that, this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following code line:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

System runs that code in fraction of second that's you can't see, Give this code.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many facts . Does your element visible . I mean for example may be you have a scrolling ? May be there is iframe ?
 If this will not help please provide  the class of your test with start and all steps , browser info...  I will try to help.

Comment: I can't add the image as a comment but please check the question, I've added it there. Hopefully that will clear some clouds.

Comment: Is div Option_0 visible ? I mean at firts try to find step by step the input . One more question may be before that input there is another element with the same name ? Check this too .also you can try to find element in html content too. Try this too. 
If this will not help provide me your class with url , setup etc .

Comment: Also is this normal page ? May be popup or it is on other tab, window ?

Comment: Another pop up window

Comment: So first you should switch to that window maybe web driver Alert class will help . After that start finding you can use pause for 2 sec before finding the element to be sure that it exists

Comment: But it's just not an alert right. I need to enter some details in the fields. This this didn't work {driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("XXXX");}

Comment: May be timing issue ? To be able to help I need your java class because we list approximately all the problems which can give exception ...

Comment: Please check the original question. I added it there.

Comment: I am actually using one of our internal servers which you cant reach. so just replaced the url.

Comment: Unfortunatly i cant check withought url . But can suggest to do the following . First add pause in your foreach . Also add exception handling . And check windows count are you on correct window or no .